# Temp Tower Setup Troubles -- Slic3r (How do you format G-Code {if} statements?)

Tags: g-code, calibration, slic3r

I watched with great interest [this video: Temp Tower - Slic3r Gcode Placeholders - How To - Chris's Basement -- Jan 23, 2019    Chris Riley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YnB9RsMN1o)

I found a model I'm happy with: [Smart compact temperature calibration tower by gaaZolee, December 24, 2017](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2729076) Uses Layer 0.20 mm  infill: 15 %

I'm testing a stubborn new spool of PLA.  Temp range of test 225 °C to 180 °C.  That model above came with recommended `if`statements.  I verified that with 100 % thickness on first layer, I'm exactly hitting all the Z targets at exactly the correct place for each temperature story on the tower.

I'm using the Slic3r "Printer Settings" tab - to place my `if` statements in place at "Before Layer Change G-Code".

It's not clear to me on the format required for a G-Code `{if}` statement.  I've tried...

```
{if layer_z == 7.8}M104 S225{endif};   // fail, this converts to: M104 S225 {endif}    
{if layer_z==1.6}M104 S225             // fail, this converts to: M104 S225    
{if [layer_z]==1.6} M104 S225          // fails, this converts to: (null)    
{if [layer_num]==8} M104 S225          // fails, this converts to: (null)    
{if layer_num==8} M104 S225          // fails, this converts to: M104 S225
```

In detail what I'm seeing is the if statements from all ten towers prints as *change temp to 225, 220, 215, 210... down to 180 (last entry)* and 180 °C is where ALL my prints get printed at.  Total Fail.

I'm just not seeing anything in the Gcode output from Slic3r that remotely looks like an `if` statement.  Any ideas here?  I've seen [this reference, on advanced conditional G-Code](https://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/conditional-gcode) but I'm just not understanding what to do here.

I do see from [Slic3r Custom G-Code Placeholder Reference](https://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/placeholder-parser), that I'm using the correct terms.   *[layer_z] - Z height of the active layer*, and *[layer_num] - Integer number of the active layer*. It's not clear if their use in "Before Layer Change G-Code" require the square brackets or not.

Any clues on how to get an if statement into G-Code via Slic3r for a temperature tower print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured this one out.  I was looking at it a bit wrong.  And here's my code:

```
; Note to self:  layer_z = [layer_z]
; T tower floor 1
{if [layer_z]==1.6} M104 S225 T0
; T tower floor 2
{if [layer_z]==11.6} M104 S220 T0
; T tower floor 3
{if [layer_z]==21.6} M104 S215 T0
; T tower floor 4
{if [layer_z]==31.6} M104 S210 T0
; T tower floor 5
{if [layer_z]==41.6} M104 S205 T0
; T tower floor 6
{if [layer_z]==51.6} M104 S200 T0
; T tower floor 7
{if [layer_z]==61.6} M104 S195 T0
; T tower floor 8
{if [layer_z]==71.6} M104 S190 T0
; T tower floor 9
{if [layer_z]==81.6} M104 S185 T0
; T tower floor 10
{if [layer_z]==91.6} M104 S180 T0
```

The key to understanding what is going on is the `; Note to self:  layer_z = [layer_z]` line.  The whole block of code above gets repeated for every layer of the print in the G-code, but it gets evaluated.  And when I search for "layer z =" and scan thru the code.. I eventually see this...

```
; Note to self:  layer_z = 1.6
; T tower floor 1
 M104 S225 T0                  <---- Yowza. Nice. 
; T tower floor 2
; T tower floor 3
; T tower floor 4
; T tower floor 5
; T tower floor 6
; T tower floor 7
; T tower floor 8
; T tower floor 9
; T tower floor 10
```

and then again:

```
; Note to self:  layer_z = 11.6
; T tower floor 1
; T tower floor 2
 M104 S220 T0           <---- Yes!
; T tower floor 3
...
```

All good. You have to have {} and [] within the code statements...

Addendum:  So it turns out things are not quite perfect.  I'm noticing at the upper floors, where things should be cooler, the temperature isn't changing.  Its locked at 215C.  I see this in the code:

```
; Note to self:  layer_z = 31.5999999999999      <--- not sure how that happened.  
; T tower floor 1
; T tower floor 2
; T tower floor 3
; T tower floor 4
; T tower floor 5
; T tower floor 6
; T tower floor 7
; T tower floor 8
; T tower floor 9
; T tower floor 10
```

`31.6` would have triggered a temperature change.  `31.5999999999999` won't do it. I need to modify the `{if... == }` to a complex test between two values...   Just wanted to share that observation here.

I do see from [this reference](https://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/conditional-gcode) that

> Expressions may be chained for an implicit AND:
>
> `{if [layer_num] == 10}{if [temperature_1] != 210}M104 S210`

And this seems to fix it:

```
; Note to self:  layer_z = [layer_z]
; T tower floor 1
{if [layer_z]<=1.65}{if [layer_z]>1.55} M104 S225 T0
; T tower floor 2
{if [layer_z]<=11.65}{if [layer_z]>11.55} M104 S220 T0
; T tower floor 3
{if [layer_z]<=21.65}{if [layer_z]>21.55} M104 S215 T0
; T tower floor 4
{if [layer_z]<=31.65}{if [layer_z]>31.55} M104 S210 T0
; T tower floor 5
{if [layer_z]<=41.65}{if [layer_z]>41.55} M104 S205 T0
; T tower floor 6
{if [layer_z]<=51.65}{if [layer_z]>51.55} M104 S200 T0
; T tower floor 7
{if [layer_z]<=61.65}{if [layer_z]>61.55} M104 S195 T0
; T tower floor 8
{if [layer_z]<=71.65}{if [layer_z]>71.55} M104 S190 T0
; T tower floor 9
{if [layer_z]<=81.65}{if [layer_z]>81.55} M104 S185 T0
; T tower floor 10
{if [layer_z]<=91.65}{if [layer_z]>91.55} M104 S180 T0
```

Comment: What firmware are you using that evaluates if statements, please?

Comment: Firmware?  I’m not sure I understand the question. I’m creating G-code using Slic3r, then inspecting the code using Atom, a piece of coding software from the folks at Github. And as for temperature problems, I’m watching the temp display as the print proceeds. Obviously something was wrong.

Comment: I'm asking what firmware, what flavor of processor on your 3d printer, is receiving this code and making these evaluations? When you set your slic3r recipes, what do you select  - repetier, marlin, sailboat, windchime, something else?

Comment: Sure,  All of those details are contained [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/what-determines-print-start-location-on-the-build-plate/11259#11259).  It's a an older MakerBot Replicator clone, actually a Flashforge Creator 1.  Firmware upgraded to Sailfish. Start/end gcode settings see link above.   Set recipes? not sure I understand what you are asking.  Question.. why are you asking?  What part of this answer makes you curious?  (or is it the odd `31.5999999999999` value?)

Comment: Thanks. If you look at https://manual.slic3r.org/expert-mode/printer-settings you'll see that your Printer recipe includes a setting for what firmware you're using.

Comment: Slic3r --> Printer Settings --> General --> Firmware, G-Code Flavor: Sailfish Makerbot   .